# C# use async method GetStringAsync visit URI why the value returned nothing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYxNd.jpg)

I want to get the returned string, but I never get it, what should I do？

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. This isn't even a screenshot which is kinda concerning. Copy and paste the code into your question.

Comment: Most probably, it is going to catch block and u r throwing from there. Make sure you have created object of httpclient and url is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I can see there are two main possible reasons for your issue,

1. Object for `HttpClient` has not defined. i.e. in your code it's `httpClient`.
2. After the program has executed the console window might have got closed as there is no statement like `Console.ReadLine();` at the end.

You can refer to this working code snippet:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    Task<string> statusCodeRunning = PreprocessingAsync();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("+++");
    }

    string statusCodeFinshed = await statusCodeRunning;

    Console.WriteLine(statusCodeFinshed);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static async Task<string> PreprocessingAsync()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        string message = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.baidu.com/");
        return message;
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Catch");
        throw;
    }
}
```